# One to Many relationship in Liferay Service Builder

Tags: java, liferay, entity, liferay-service-builder

I've started learning Liferay (6.2) about a week ago for a project. I've used "pure" Java EE before (JSP, JSF, etc.) with JPA (EclipseLink).

What I can't understand is:

How to use `ServiceBuilder` to create entities that behave like the ones I defined before For e.g.: if I define a `Category` and a `CategoryProperty` entity, which are in a one-to-many relationship, I can only define a finder to the `CategoryProperty` which returns all the `CategoryProperty`s by the **parent** `categoryId`.

Based on the book I'm reading, I can only modify the implementation of the `CategoryLocalServiceImpl` and the `CategoryPropertyLocalServiceImpl` and can't touch the generated entities. So if I want to list every `CategoryProperty` which belongs to one Category, I have to implement and call **`CategoryPropertyLocalServiceUtil.findAllByCategoryId(categoryId)`** which is not what i want. The **`category.getCategoryProperties()`** call would be much more natural.

How do I achieve that without messing up the whole structure? Which generated classes can I touch? what is that I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly, what you understand is right but it's not the whole story.

You can catch what you want implementing method `getCategoryProperties()` in `CategoryImpl` class.

That method will use the finder method you previously made and describe in the question.

Comment: After I modify the CategoryImpl I just have to re-run the ServiceBuilder ant?

Comment: Yes,  rerun the service builder

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)